# CloudFront with Edge Side Includes?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, varnish, edge-side-includes

I've only recently been reading up on the capabilities of Varnish Cache to help optimize my PHP website's performance.  I read about a feature called Edge Side Includes, which seems to give me the option to build widgets of html content that can be cached on a component level. So that a single page of dynamic content can have parts of the page cached, and other parts not cached.

I then started to look into Amazon CloudFront, which seems to offer page level caching abilities as well.  But it isn't clear to me if CloudFront offers the equivalent of Edge Side Includes.   Can someone clarify for me if that is possible? This would influence the way I architect my PHP website.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Cloudfront does not support ESI at this date.

You have three options moving forward.

1. Don't cache content this content in Cloudfront
2. Cache but with a low TTL. E.g. cache pages in Cloudfront with a TTL of only 1-20min depending on your application needs.
3. Implement a backgrund job that invalidates the Cloudfront cache when something is changed. Beware that Cloudfront have a few limitations on how many concurrent invalidation jobs that can run at the same time. I.e. if your content changes often this might not work. [Read more about these limits here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#InvalidationLimits).

**Update**
You might be able to achieve ESI functionality with Cloudflare and the use of their "Workers" [Cloudflare Workers and ESI](https://blog.cloudflare.com/edge-side-includes-with-cloudflare-workers/)

Comment: I would also add an option of using Lambda@Edge functions to parse the response for ESI tags and processing them. I have not actually tried this, nor can I find any libraries to do this. However reviewing the Lambda@Edge docs, it seems possible with the functionality offered.

Comment: Lambda@edge will not work, as per their docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-updating-http-responses.html:

When you're working with the HTTP response, Lambda@Edge does not expose the body that is returned by the origin server to the origin-response trigger. You can generate a static content body by setting it to the desired value, or remove the body inside the function by setting the value to be empty. If you don't update the body field in your function, the original body returned by the origin server is returned back to viewer.